# Sócio majoritário tem hífen?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico, hífen

Estou com dúvida quanto ao uso do hífen no caso de **sócio majoritário** (ou minoritário).

Numa busca na internet, não vi nenhum site de boa reputação que usa a grafia com hífen.

Entranto, no site de [dicas de português do UOL](https://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/entenda-o-uso-do-hifen-em-socio-fundador-e-socioeconomico.jhtm), eles explicam que outras variações com a palavra "sócio" levam hífen, como **sócio-fundador**, **sócio-gerente** e **sócio-diretor**.

Por essa lógica, o correto seria **sócio-majoritário** (com hífen). Mas não vejo essa forma sendo usada na imprensa, em sites jurídicos, e na internet em geral.

Qual seria a forma correta?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O emprego do hífen seria aceito se "sócio majoritário" fosse um composto homogêneo, duas palavras de gênero igual, como dois substantivos ou dois adjetivos. Ao meu ver neste caso você tem um substantivo "sócio" e um adjetivo ao sócio que seria "majoritário" ou "minoritário", não se referindo ao cargo ou título da pessoa e sim quanto a pessoa têm sobre o negócio.

Acho que essa identificação de adjetivo fica mais clara nos exemplos, "sócio rico" ou "sócio pobre". Nestes exemplos não usamos hífen pelo mesmo motivo "rico" e "pobre" são adjetivos para a palavra "sócio".

Nos exemplos que você citou do UOL são diferentes, pois se referem ao cargo da pessoa, "sócio-fundador" ou "sócio-gerente" são dois substantivos e neste caso temos o tal do "composto homogêneo".

Fonte sobre uso de hífen: http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono27.php